# How can I make this layout?

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I am a new comer in android. I've tried to make a layout like picture below but I can't make it. 
[image]

That rectangle is an image and two others are text view. I've tried to make it but it always wrong. Looking forward to hearing from you guys, thanks for advance.

Comment: Can you post your code, and describe what it's producing

Comment: I would suggest posting some code then we can suggest what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define one layout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@+id/rlGridRow"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    >  
<ImageView    
    android:id="@+id/imageView01"    
    android:layout_width="36.0dip"  
    android:layout_height="36.0dip"  
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"  
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />  
<TextView android:id="@+id/txtLink1"  
    android:paddingLeft="6.0dip"    
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:textColor="#FF00FF"  
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView01" />  
<TextView android:id="@+id/txtLink2"  
    android:paddingLeft="6.0dip"    
    android:paddingBottom="8.0dip"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:textColor="#00FFFF"  
    android:textSize="12sp"  
    android:layout_marginTop="-4.0dip" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView01"  
    android:layout_below="@id/txtLink1" />  
</RelativeLayout>
```

See [this](http://blog.csdn.net/ameyume/archive/2011/05/09/6407393.aspx) link for additional info.